# Can I create a new class in Sublime text 2?

Tags: c++, class, sublimetext2

I have a question. I am learning C++ with Bucky's C++ Programming Tutorials on youtube. I am on the 15th video, and in that video he uses CodeBlocks to place his classes in a separate folder by going to "File/New/Class" a popup menu appears and it automatically creates a .h and a .cpp file setup with the class you want.

I want to know if I can create a new class just like that in sublime text 2. Or if there is a plugin for doing so.

Im very sorry if the title is misleading at all, but that was really the only way I could think of to word it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also: My operating system is OSX Mavericks.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the Software Recommendations exchange.

Comment: sorry, I have never heard of that website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Sublime has this option as it is not a a IDE but rather a fancy text editor, even though I guess some people use it as [an IDE](http://www.chromium.org/developers/sublime-text). 
I would recommend using [qtcreator](https://qt-project.org/downloads) or [code::blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads). 
However if you are new to programming it is a good exercise to learn how to link your classes from scratch, and not have them linked and compiled for you with 2 mouse clicks.

Comment: I do know how to link them manually, however it would be nicer to have the files done in 2 clicks. I am not a beginner programmer though, I know html, css, javascript, python, a little bit of swift, and a little bit of c++. Though I do hope there is a plugin for automatically creating classes.

Comment: I find qtcreator to be the best out of the non-commercial IDEs and would run on Mavericks... Try it out, as it seems that making sublime do the same would be a hassle. Whereas in your avg IDE you get all that and much more... If you are looking to ease your workflow, then use that which is easiest :)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text Editor doesn't provide this facility. Classes can be separated only in IDEs like MS VisualStudios and CodeBlocks.
In further videos, Bucky will use the separation of classes, but that stuff can also be done without separating the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you still looking for a sublime text plugin for creating classes.. I’ve written a plugin for that a few months ago. 
You can install it via package control -> https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2B%20Classhelper

But it only creates classes (header file, source file) but it is not adding the targets to a makefile.